# Need to pass a jqgrid column name to function triggered by the "onclickSubmit" event

Tags: jqgrid

I need to pass or make available a jqgrid colModel column name to a function triggered by the jqgrid event **"onclickSubmit:"** defined in the edit options of navGrid - but i don't know how to do that.

here are the jqgrid and javascript code segments:

```
..., onclickSubmit: fixpostdata}, // navGrid edit options
.
.
. 
var fixpostdata = function(params, postdata){
    var rowid = $('#tab3-grid').getGridParam('selrow');

    // when the onclickSubmit event fires and calls this function,
    // a string containing a jqgrid colmodel column name needs to be
    // made available in order to modify that cell's value contained
    // in the postdata array prior to posting it to the server.

    columnName =  ???;

    var value = $('#tab3-grid').jqGrid('getCell', rowid, columnName );

    postdata[ columnName ] = value;

    return;
}
```

Can anyone help?
also,
what's contained in the params argument?

Comment: Something is wrong in what you want to archive. The callback function [onclickSubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) will be called before submitting of the whole form. So it's independent on any grid column. Moreover I don't see any relation of your question to jQuery UI Autocomplete. Try to change the text of your question to describe *original problem* which you have. The usage of `onclickSubmit` is already an implementation way which could be not the best one.

Comment: @Oleg - Ok... i re-worded the question to be more clear.  I'm using the onclickSubmit event because according the jqgrid doc, it makes the postdata array available for modification after construction and before posting it to the server.  The function needs to know the name of the column before it can modify its value in the postdata array.  The method works perfectly with the column name hardwired in the function but i want to make the function usable to other grids with different column names that the function needs.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean because jqGrid *send automatically* the information about modified columns in the format which you need. You don't should do anything. In the posted data will be included `id` and the values of *all editable columns*. The names of columns will be used as the names of parameters which will be send to the server. The default name of rowid parameter is `id`. Additionally will be send `oper` parameter with the value "edit", "add" or "del". You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to examine HTTP trafic.

Comment: @Oleg - The answer i'm seeking is due to the way jqgrid determines what's put into the postdata array on editform submit. A jqgrid field of edittype:'select' displays the select label and jqgrid puts the select value into the postdata array. However, using jquery UI autocomplete in jqgrid editoptions dataqinit: requires a field of edittype:'text'. jqgrid's default action is to put what's displayed in the text box into the postdata array. I want to display the selected autocomplete label but need to post the value.

Comment: So, I save the value in a hidden column when the autocomplete select: event is triggered. The value is then retrieved by the fixpostdata function when it's triggered by the jqgrid onclickSubmit event. the function then replaces the label with the value in the postdata array prior to being sent to the server. But in order to retrieve the stored value, the function needs to know the rowid and column name where the value is stored.

Comment: By default autocomplete displays the value of the selected label/value pair in the list in the text box. In order to display the label in the text box, i prevent default action then insert the label into the text box and save the value in the hidden column cell when the autocomplete select: event is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to send contain of some hidden column to the server together with other editable columns you need include `editable: true` in the hidden column and add one more property

```
editrules: { edithidden: false }
```

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you prefer i make the hidden column editable so jqgrid will see it and add it to the postdata array on submit but at the same time hide it in the edit form. This would eliminate the need for the onclickSubmit event and it's triggered function to update the postdata array.  The php script would then look for and act on the existence of the hidden column name posted to the server. That would work. However, if i wanted to make the hidden column name available to the triggered function, how would i do it?

Comment: @NelsonM: I don't understand what you mean under "jqgrid will see it". If I understand you correct *you have already hidden column* which data you want send during form editing. In the case my suggestion is mostly close to what you need. If you just add to the hidden column `editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: false }` you will have exactly the same results as with respect of `onclickSubmit`. I suppose that you implemented in the server code all what you need.

Comment: I simply mean that your suggestion will allow the hidden column to be visible to jqgrid in the editform for the purpose of including it in the postdata array while being hidden from the users view. In jqgrid, a hidden column by default is not included in the postdata array when the editform is submited.

Comment: If jqgrid had a edittype:'autocomplete' that functioned like the 'select' edittype, we wouldn't be having this Q&A.  But i'd still like to know how to pass data to the fixpostdata function.

Comment: @NelsonM: My suggestion means that the hidden column which you want to send will be **not visible**, but the information from the column will be *included* in the form **as hidden data** and then it will be send to the server in exactly the same format which you described in your question. Just try this and you will see the results. There are no `edittype:'autocomplete'`. The question about `fixpostdata` function is wrong state. If you want to send some information from some hidden column to the server you have to know *which* information you need. So I don't understand code `columnName = ???`

Comment: We are in agreement on how your suggestion functions. I'll accept your answer.  But what do you mean by "fixpostdata function is wrong state"?

Comment: @NelsonM: I mean, that the question is wrong formulated. In the comments you wrote "I save the value in a hidden column when the autocomplete select: event is triggered" and then "the function needs to know the rowid and column name where the value is stored". So I understood your question so: you save an additional information in the hidden column and you want to send the information to the server. The column name where you save the additional information you should know yourself. The id is in `postdata.id`, but I think you can send the same information just with `edithidden`. Isn't it so?

Comment: If the same function is used by other grids with different hidden column names, then the function would need to know which one. If i where using the function on just one grid, then yes, the function would know the column name. Either way, your answer and method is the best solution - thank you.

Comment: @NelsonM: You are welcome! I don't like the solution which you use with autocomplete. I think that one can suggest better way, but I don't know your full environment. So I think if the solution work, then I try to change less in your current solution. If you include in the grid where you use Autocomplete additional hidden column which you need to send, you can just add to the column the settings which I describe. Then you don't need any additional customization and can more share your code for many grids like you as want. If you don't thing so, you can unaccept the answer and modify your quest

Comment: Nope, i'll keep your solution.